# couchdb map function gives compilation_error

Tags: couchdb-futon

Am new to couchdb2.0,working on map function.I have written a function

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.entityType!=null){
     if(doc.cityName!=null && doc.locationName!=null){

     var key =[doc.cityName,doc.locationName,doc.entityType]

     emit(key, doc);
    }
  }
}
```

which is throwing

> > {"error":"compilation_error","reason":"Expression does not eval to a function. >>(function(doc) {\n if(doc.cityName!=null && doc.entityType!=null){key=>>[doc.cityName,doc.entityType] emit(key, doc);\n}})"}

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon to the end of the `key` variable instantiation:

```
var key =[doc.cityName,doc.locationName,doc.entityType];
```